# Swift conditional compiling didn't work properly when I use macro defined in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, swift

I define a simple macro in objective-c header file, and import this header file into Swift through project bridging header. I was able to use this macro as a constant in Swift, but when I use it to do conditional compiling, it doesn't work properly.

I create a simple project in Xcode 10.2.1 and add some code to reproduce it.
In ViewController.h

```c
#define TEST_FLAG 1

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

In ViewController.m

```
#import "testMacro-Swift.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SwiftClass *s = [[SwiftClass alloc] init];
    [s printMSG];

#if TEST_FLAG
    NSLog(@"Objc works.");
#endif
}
```

In testMacro-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```

SwiftFile

```
@objc class SwiftClass: NSObject {
    @objc func printMSG() {
        print("Macro \(TEST_FLAG)")
        #if TEST_FLAG
        print("compiled XXXxXXXXX")
        #endif
    }
}
```

Console Output

```
Macro 1
2019-07-03 14:38:07.370231-0700 testMacro[71724:11911063] Objc works.
```

I expected `compiled XXXxXXXXX` to be printed after `Macro 1`, but it not.

I am curious why this will happen.
My project is mixed with objc and swift. I don't want to declare a same flag in swift.

Comment: I do import objc file in bridging header. you can see `print("Macro \(TEST_FLAG)")` runs, and print correct TEST_FLAG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this Apple article, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_macros_in_swift, simple C (and Objective-C) macros are imported into Swift as global constants.  This is demonstrated by the output from your line

```
print("Macro \(TEST_FLAG)")
```

The snippet

```
    #if TEST_FLAG
    print("compiled XXXxXXXXX")
    #endif
```

uses a different `TEST_FLAG`, which is a Swift preprocessor flag.  You could define it under Build Settings -> Active Compilation Conditions as `TEST_FLAG` or under Build Settings -> Other Swift Flags as `-DTEST_FLAG`.

The above explains why this happens.  I can't think of a simple way to avoid defining the same flag separately for Objective-C and Swift preprocessor in Xcode.  If you just want to control whether some Swift code is **executed** based on the `TEST_FLAG`, you can do something like this:

```
if TEST_FLAG != 0 {
        print("compiled XXXxXXXXX")
}
```

However, if you want to control **compilation** of the code, then you may have to use separate `TEST_FLAG`s for Objective-C and Swift and make sure they are consistent.  To aid in making them consistent, you could set the `TEST_FLAG` used by Objective-C code in `Other C Flags`, which allow you to define different flags for different SDKs, Architectures, and build types (Release/Debug).  Active Compilation Conditions allow the same flexibility.

Another trick to facilitate consistency between (Objective-)C and Swift compiler flags is to create a new user-defined build setting: click on `+` to the left of the search box under Build Settings.

Say, call it `COMMON_TEST_FLAG` and set its value to `TEST_FLAG`.  Then add `-D$(COMMON_TEST_FLAG)` to Other C Flags and Other Swift Flags.  Now when you build your code `TEST_FLAG` will be defined in both Objective-C and Swift code within your target.  If you don't want it to be defined, just change the value of `COMMON_TEST_FLAG` to something else.  A couple of things to watch for, though:

- You cannot make `COMMON_TEST_FLAG` empty: this will cause the other
  flags to be just -D, leading to a build error.
- Make sure the value of `COMMON_TEST_FLAG`does not conflict with
  macros defined elsewhere.

Comment: But that is not conditional compilation, which is what the question is about.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, @matt.  I read the question too hurriedly.  Modified the answer.

Comment: I'd love to know more about this. I wish there was an article that uses an example so that we can understand how we can use a macro constant defined in objective-C from a swift file to conditionally add code to a file (like we can with `#ifdef`)

Answer (score 2):

Swift's preprocessor is (intentionally) waaaaaaay more limited than C's. Macros come with really serious draw backs.

1. They define regions of code that aren't active in every build target. Because of this, your tests won't be hitting every branch (or even compiling every branch). This quickly becomes a maintenance disaster. For `n` unique flags, there are 2^n`possible sets of values and thus,`2^n` possible builds. Do you have to test each of them? Maybe, maybe not, but even just reasoning about what to test isn't easy.
2. They can get tangled up and incredibly complex, especially with nested blocks.

In general, try to express as much of your code in the main programming language (C, ObjC, Swift), and resort to using macros only when there's a good reason, such as:

1. Reducing repetition in a way that can't be done with a function.
2. Improving performance in a critical region of code (by forcing inlining of macro code, e.g. `#define max(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (b) : (a))`). Though this is exceptionally rare.
3. Expressing a piece of logic that can't be expressed in the language. For example, there's no way to express `if #available(...)` in Swift, without using the preprocessor.

Your example doesn't meet any of these criteria. It's *increasing* repetition, it's not performance-critical, and it's not doing something that can't be done in regular Swift code.

A much better approach to this (in both Swift and Objective C), is to create a logger that is initialized with different configurations between debug and release builds. Your `viewDidLoad` method should not concern itself whether or not `TEST_FLAG` is set. View controllers should control views, not make decisions as to what things should be logged. It should just call the logger to send off whatever log messages it wants to send, and leave it up to the logger to decide how to log those messages (to an output stream, file, in-memory circular buffer, database, stream to an analytics API, ignore them, etc.)