# Swift Compiler Flags Wont affect Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

under `Active Compilation Conditions` i have added a new flag (for debug only) called `SOMEFLAG`.
the check is implemented like so and works great:

```
#if SOMEFLAG
   print("SOMEFLAG is true");
#endif
```

it actually prints like i would expect. now, i need to examine the same flag from `Objective-C` class and it never evaluates to true. any idea why?
should i make this flag in other way?
in general my goal is to be able to detect when it is executed from another target, the build is triggered from the `cli`. 
if there is other way that less limiting i would like to know.

thanks!

Comment: See if this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878455/swift-conditional-compiling-didnt-work-properly-when-i-use-macro-defined-in-obj/56879257#56879257

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C (and other C-like languages that use a preprocessor) the canonical way to check whether a symbol is defined would be using `#ifdef`, not `#if`. There is an `#if` directive in Objective-C, but it doesn't behave quite the same way as the Swift `#if` compiler directive.